# Bootstrap not working well with toastr

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toastr

I use it in my php function, and now I get a error in php I think thats te problem, ( SyntaxError: missing ; before statement line 133 ) my php function is :

```css
<?php
function VISION_TO_REPORT_MESSAGES($report_tag = "test", $subject_parameters = '', $message_parameters = '', $output=true, $lang = '')
{
// action report messages templates ...
 $report_tag = strtolower(trim($report_tag));
if (strlen($report_tag))
{        

  $report_message = array();
  $db = new clsDBcms();
        $SQL = " SELECT * FROM report_messages WHERE  report_tag= " . $db->ToSQL($report_tag, ccsText) . " LIMIT 1 ";  
       $db->query($SQL);
    $Result = $db->next_record();
    if ($Result)
 {
  $report_message['lang'] = $db->f("lang");
  if(function_exists("VISION_TO_TRANSLATE"))
  {
  $report_message['subject'] = VISION_TO_MULTI_CONTENT($db->f("subject"),$lang);
  $report_message['message'] = VISION_TO_MULTI_CONTENT($db->f("message"),$lang);
  }
  else
  {
  $report_message['subject'] = $db->f("subject");
  $report_message['message'] = $db->f("message");
  }

  $report_message['css'] = $db->f("css");
  $report_message['redirect_to'] = $db->f("redirect_to");
  $report_message['type'] = $db->f("type");

   if(!empty($subject_parameters))
   {
   while (list($this_tag,$value) = each($subject_parameters))
   $report_message['subject']  = preg_replace("/".$this_tag."/i", $value, $report_message['subject']);
   }

   if(!empty($message_parameters))
   {
   while (list($this_tag,$value) = each($message_parameters))
   $report_message['message']  = preg_replace("/".$this_tag."/i", $value, $report_message['message']);
   }
  }
        $db->close();
  if($output == true && isset($report_message['message']))
  //$output = '<script type="text/javascript">';
  $output = 'toastr.options ={ 
    "closeButton": false,
   "debug": false,
   "newestOnTop": false,
   "progressBar": true,
   "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
   "preventDuplicates": false,
   "onclick": null,
   "showDuration": "300",
   "hideDuration": "1000",
   "timeOut": "5000",
   "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
   "showEasing": "swing",
   "hideEasing": "linear",
   "showMethod": "fadeIn",
   "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
   }';
  $output .=  'toastr.' . $report_message['css'] . "('" . str_replace("'", "\\'", htmlentities($report_message['message'])) . "'" . (isset($report_message['subject']) ? ", '" . str_replace("'", "\\'", htmlentities($report_message['subject'])) . "'" : null) . ');';
        return $output;
    }  
 }
?>
```

line 133 in my html is   :

toastr.success('The User record has been successfully updated.', 'Record Updated.');

In THE head of my page I use :

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.2/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.js"></script>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you include the JS files correctly? Then there is `toastr options` - isn't there a dot missing in between? And `toastr-success` is also `toastr.success('Oh, no all dots missing');`

Comment: Open the debug console of Edge, IE, Chrome or FireFox and check witch errors appear to you. It might not loading the jquery file correctly

Comment: Where's the bootstrap?

Comment: I use boostrap 3.3.5 I do Have this in my head

<head>
  <link href="assets/toastr-master/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="assets/toastr-master/toastr.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: I'd recommend using CodePen or JSFiddle for your example...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any complications when adding bootstrap to **toastr** but your code does have some problems:

1. First and foremost, if you're going to share code, please try to include the necessary libraries to actually run it.  You can use my example below, or the instructions on the [toastr](/questions/tagged/toastr) tag.
2. `toastr options = {` should have a period to access the `options` property on the `toastr` object, like this: `toastr.options = {`
3. Same thing for `toastr-success('The...` which should use a period, not a hyphen to call the success method like this: `toastr.success('The...`
4. If you automatically escape `<strong>` into `&lt;strong&gt;` then there is no possible chance it will be rendered as html.  **It's already been escaped!**  So you need to include the brackets as you would regular html and then tell toastr to [not escape it](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#escape-html-characters) like this: `toastr.options.escapeHtml = false;`

Here's a working demo in Stack Snippets - please use this as a future template when asking questions so people can see where the actual problems are in your code.

```js
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": true,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
  "escapeHtml": false
}

toastr.success('The <strong>User</strong> record has been successfully updated.', 'Record Updated.');
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.2/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.js"></script>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks kyleMit, I have change THE toastr code, but nou I have this error ( see above, I have change my question )